# HtmlUnit throws many exceptions on clicking one button

Tags: java, yahoo, htmlunit

I'm trying to create program that signs in to [Yahoo](https://login.yahoo.com/config/login) account.
I'm using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) in Java, but when the program is trying to cick *Sign In* button it throws a large number of various exceptions.

The button form is:

```
<form method="post" action="https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?" autocomplete="" name="login_form" onsubmit="return hash2(this)">
    <input type="hidden" name=".tries" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".src" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".md5" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".hash" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".js" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".last" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="promo" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".intl" value="us"/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".bypass" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".partner" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".u" value="eqn7kn96q7irv"/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".v" value="0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".challenge" value="rTRqt.vaVyBEJgxmMpkh0sqYx5Mz"/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".yplus" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".emailCode" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="pkg" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="stepid" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".ev" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hasMsgr" value="0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".chkP" value="Y"/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".done" value="http://my.yahoo.com"/>
    <input type="hidden" name=".pd" value="_ver=0&c=&ivt=&sg="/>
    <input type="hidden" name="pad" id="pad" value="3"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="aad" id="aad" value="3"/>
    <div id="inputs">
    <div id="fun"/>
    <div id="persistency">
    <div id="submit">
        <button type="submit" id=".save" name=".save" class="primaryCta" tabindex="5"> Sign In </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my java code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.RefreshHandler;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButton;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class VirtualWebBrowser {

    public static void clickAuthorizeButton(String url, String login, String password) throws Exception {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
            public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("handleRefresh");
            }
        });

        HtmlPage loginPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);
        HtmlForm liginForm = loginPage.getFormByName("login_form");

        liginForm.getInputByName("login").setValueAttribute(login);
        liginForm.getInputByName("passwd").setValueAttribute(password);

        HtmlButton signInButton = liginForm.getButtonByName(".save");
        HtmlPage nextPage = (HtmlPage) signInButton.click();

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
}
```

All exceptions is in the line `HtmlPage nextPage = (HtmlPage) signInButton.click();`

After this line program is logged in Yahoo account but these all exceptions somehow affects all program work that it works unstably. 
What should I do to avoid this situation or at least catch all exceptions?

Comment: Could you provide more information on what exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: All exceptions are there: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/tQ5Osdrrbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the errors you pasted it looks like one of those cases where the HTMLUnit Javascript implementation differs from the one in browser. I also wouldn't be surprised if Yahoo didn't want people to perform automatic login into their properties.

Instead of wrestling with Javascript here I would try the following things:

1. Look at HTTP communication using a sniffer (like HttpFox) and try to send login request using HTTPURLConnection or HTTPClient.
2. See if you can login using the API. I know Yahoo provides OpenID, they also might provide OAuth authentication, see http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/
3. Use Selenium to login using real browser.